# Wso2 API manager integration with Openam

Tags: wso2, openam

I'm trying to integrated wso2 api manager in our organization. We are using Open AM as out Single sign on. I tried to search for some documentation for it but couldn't find any for wso2  API manager authentication and possibly authorization piece integration with Open AM. Is there any extension or plugin available to integrate it?

Appreciate if have any idea about this. Thanks in advance!

Regards, 
Jayesh

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this blog post in [1]. Here I done it for WSO2 BAM. Same as you can do it for WSO2 AM.

[1] http://manulachathurika.blogspot.com/2013/10/configure-opensso-for-wso2-business.html