# How to integrate WSO2 api manager 2.0.0 with OpenAM for usermanagement?

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager, openam, ibm-api-management

I'm trying to integrate WSO2 with OpenAm for user management. Can anyone provide me the steps for integrating.?

Comment: in general .... OpenAM is not really an Identity Management / provisioning tool. You can use it's IdM features only in specific cases and you need to understand the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer in [1]. It has done for WSO2 BAM. Same as you can do it for WSO2 AM.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268640/1246467